# Возможно ли отловить ошибку WinApi на C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

Добрый вечер, товарищи!

В проекте на C# понадобилось использовать WinApi. В том числе - метод GetWindowText. И все бы было нормально, если бы GetWindowText переодически не выкидывал ошибку Access_Denied при переборе списка хэндлеров и не ломал всего сущего.

Вопрос следующий: можно ли как-то отловить и отработать ошибку (аки try-catch, который тут работать отказывается) или же проверить наличие у меня доступа к элементу, имея только его IntPtr хэндлер?

Пример кода:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);
            public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
public static IntPtr[] FindWindowsByName(string Name)
            {
                List<IntPtr> windows = new List<IntPtr>();
            EnumWindows(delegate (IntPtr wnd, IntPtr param)
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    int code = GetWindowText(wnd, str, GetWindowTextLength(wnd) + 1);
                    if (str.ToString().Contains(Name)) windows.Add(wnd);
                } catch { }
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
            return windows.ToArray();
            }
```

Падает все именно при получении текста окна (не любого, элементов 20 проходит нормально), отладчик выдает, что возвращена ошибка Access Denied. Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибку и объясните, что я не так делаю

Comment: GetWindowText Если функция завершается успешно, возвращаемое значение - длина, в символах, скопированной строки, не, включая символа конца строки (нуль-терминатора). Если у окна нет заголовка или текста, если строка заголовка - пустая строка или, если дескриптор окна или органа управления недопустимы, возвращаемое значение нулевое. Чтобы получать расширенные данные об ошибках, вызовите GetLastError.

Comment: @koshkashoshka это я знаю. Код ошибки 0x00...05 = Access_Denied. Видимо, среди перебираемого мною листа хэндлеров затесывается какой-то системный процесс, запрещающий себя читать, откуда и вылетает такая ошибка. Потому я и хочу узнать, можно ли найти какой-то аналог try-catch для этого или, что даже лучше, определить наличие у меня полномочий на чтение элемента

Comment: аналог называется if (ret_value == 0x50) { ... } Какой еще try-catch, когда нет исключения?

Comment: @koshkashoshka нет, ну по факту-то ошибка есть. Только инвочится она в неуправляемой среде. А то, что вы предлагаете, можно получить лишь после того, как у меня приложение крашнулось, так что не думаю, что это именно то, что мне поможет

Comment: В неуправляемом коде не бывает никаких "ошибка инвочится". На то он и не управляемый - либо работает, либо сломался. Как вам уже сказали, `GetWindowText` должна срабатывать всегда, и в случае проблем просто возвращать 0. Если у вас при этом падает приложение, то вероятно вы делаете что-то не так. Вы, кстати, уверены, что программа валится именно на вызове `GetWindowText`? Боюсь, что без [минимального примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) тут не обойтись.

Comment: Могу предположить, что он использует не DllImport (pinvoke), а какую-то managed-обертку для слабаков. Если не так, и try-catch не помогает, то пусть поставит exception handler на весь поток/приложение xD

Comment: @playerone обновил вопрос, добавил пример кода

Comment: @playerone, а разве `SetLastError = true` не привыодит к выбрасыванию исключенения, если функция завершилась ошибкой?

Comment: @playerone, нет, не он, а [`PreserveSig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за наводку, не знал о `PreserveSig`. Впрочем, из его описания следует, что экспешены должны ловиться нормально. Ожидать другого было бы странно. А ТС сразу сообщил, что try/catch не помогает. Ну и `GetWindowText` возвращает не `HRESULT`, если уж позанудствовать.

Comment: @playerone, ну так у него нет PreserveSig в приведённом коде, есть только SetLastError.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вижу. Я просто подумал, что вы меня упрекаете, мол я дезинформировал человека, утверждением, что нативный код не может кидать эксепшенов. Вот и отвечаю, что тут как ни крути, а дело не могло быть в `PreserveSig`. Видимо мы друг друга недопоняли :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы выделяете пустой буфер, и сообщаете функции `GetWindowText`, что его длина равна `GetWindowTextLength(wnd) + 1`. Неудивительно, что вы затираете какую-то чужую память и падаете.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(); // нулевого размера
int code = GetWindowText(wnd, str, GetWindowTextLength(wnd) + 1);
```

[Вот тут](http://improve.dk/enumerating-windows/) пример, который делает то же самое. Интересующая нас часть кода (немного изменена):

```
int txtLength = GetWindowTextLength(wnd);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(txtLength + 1);
int code = GetWindowText(wnd, str, str.Capacity);
```

---

Вы должны быть **очень** осторожны с P/Invoke, понимать в деталях значение каждой строчки и заглядывать в документацию к **каждой** вызываемой функции. Управляемый код прощает ошибки и контролирует вас, а вот нативный код требует отчётливо понимать, что вы делаете и для чего.

---

По поводу вопроса, вынесенного в заголовок. В общем случае, ошибки в нативном коде ловятся очень сложно, они не заявляют о себе прямо, а приводят к крешам (в лучшем случае), к крешам в совсем другом месте и в другое время (в более плохом случае), и к молчаливому «необъяснимому» неправильному поведению нормального кода (в ужасном случае). Старайтесь избегать нативного кода, если вы не уверены в собственных силах.

Comment: Вы святой человек! Спасибо большое! Не первый раз мне, дураку, помогаете хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Пожалуйста! Добавил ссылку на работающий пример, если что.

Comment: спасибо огромное!